# C++ SFML - How to make bouncing sprite?

Tags: c++, game-physics, sfml

I try to make 2D game with C++ using SFML. I have drawn sprite and now I want to make that sprite moving automatically to random direction and when it hit wall then it bounce away and change direction. I don't know how to do auto moving sprite what bounce from wall... So please help me.

Answer (score 2):

`sf::Sprite` has a member function `setPosition (float x, float y)` that you can use to set the position of the sprite before it's drawn. By moving the sprite to a new position each frame you create the impression of movement, much like a cartoon. By comparing the position of the sprite with the position of other elements in your scene, like the walls, you can calculate when 2 objects hit and take appropriate action. Typically it works like this:

- Reset a clock at the beginning of a new frame, you can use `sf::Clock` or C++'s chrono for example.
- Update the position of all elements in the scene that should be moving with something like:  `ObjectSpeed * Previous frame time`
- Draw the frame
- Save time elapsed for calculating the next frame
- Loop